# Изменить масштаб изображения

Tags: c#, winforms, изображения

Задача состоит в том, чтобы изменять градус поворота и масштаб изображения в Windows Forms с помощью TrackBar'a. С поворотом разобрался, но вот с масштабом все никак.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private float Ang = 0;
        private float Ang1 = 0;
        Bitmap g = new Bitmap(Imame.Value);

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(g.Width / 2, g.Height / 2);
            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(Ang);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(g, new Point(-g.Width / 2, -g.Height / 2));
        }

        private void ScaleTransformFloat(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(Ang1, 1.0F);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(g, new Point(-g.Width / 2, -g.Height / 2));
        }


        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Ang = (float)numericUpDown1.Value;
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Ang1 = (float)trackBar1.Value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В смысле не выдерживает?

Comment: @axmed2004 да я просто имел ввиду, что вылетает ошибка, при попытке загрузить изображения.

Comment: Будет лучше если вы приведете текст ошибки

Comment: @axmed2004 Как-то так [ссылка](https://ibb.co/DVdCLPC)

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать после каждого вызова события заново переопределять Bitmap.